# Can the NOTE and WARNING styles be modified in Kate?

Tags: kate

Would you please tell me where in the configuration settings can the styling of the uppercase NOTE and WARNING text be set within comments?

I copied over an existing theme to modify a bit in an attempt to lessen eye fatigue and just can't find that setting.

Thank you.

Comment: "I copied over an existing them..." could you clarify this statement? Have you looked into documentation for this application to see if there are theming options availble?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking under Configure Kate => Color Themes => Theme Editor tab => Default Text Style tab. That was okay for most of it; but I didn't realize the NOTE and WARNING are specific to Tcl/Tk scripts; and that is on the tab to the right entitled Highlighting Text Styles and you can select to which "language" the styling applies for your copied theme. It is under Alert, and NOTE and WARNING are under Alert Level 2 and 3.

It would not accept un-bolding the text. It would uncheck the box but once Apply was clicked, the check was back on and the text was still bold. After exiting the menu and looking under another script language, the un-bolding was accepted in the menu and in the actual text.

There are many, many options and, if have the time to spend, I suppose you can get just about whatever you want in your copied theme.